# Speeding up Python Numpy code

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have the following code:

```
big_k = gabor((height * 2, width *2), (height, width))
for r_slice in range(0,radialSlices):
  r_pixels = r_slice * radialWidth
  for a_slice in range(0,angularSlices):
    a_pixels = a_slice * angularWidth
    k_win = big_k[height - r_pixels:2*height - r_pixels,width - a_pixels:2 * width - a_pixels]
    result = np.sum(img * k_win)
```

`img` is a `uint8` array of 640x480, and `big_k` is `complex64` 1280x960.

This code amounts to 1024 640x480 matrix multiplications and a cast to complex64.

This code takes on the order of 2 seconds to run on my macbook; I'm looking to try and get a speedup of the order of 100x. What can I do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, this just looks like a big convolution. If that's the case, try one of Scipy's convolution functions, or use an FFT-based convolution approach.

Comment: The idea is to apply a filter centred at several points across an image, and then take the sum of the values of the result at each point. Come to think about it it is similar to a convolution. Could I just convolve the two and then take the results at each point across? There would be no need to sum either in that case AFAIK? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Basically, yes. A convolution is likely to be much faster, and you can obtain the results at every point in the image (or just at selected points, your choice). Try `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`.

Comment: OK That's fabulous- I just tried it. Speedup is on the order of 2-3x - which is a huge improvement, plus a much 'sexier' solution. This completely changes the code, so I guess this question is answered! I can continue to optimise from here. If you want to write the answer below I'll accept it! Thanks!

Comment: The convolution is going to compute 640*480 = 307200 values, of which you say you only need 1024. There seems to be a ~300x speed-up hiding somewhere in there...

Comment: Thanks Jaime, any suggestions where I might look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing looks kind of a like a convolution, so I'd recommend trying to implement it using a convolution operation. Convolutions can be computed very efficiently with an FFT-based approach, and are implemented in SciPy as `scipy.signal.fftconvolve`.